# SSDT generate incremental without database compare

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, deployment, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I need a direction on Database Project deployments in VS 2015.

We have database project in our application, which we deployed in Production database server. later, we don't have access to production database server due to security reasons.

We need to give the customer the database changes as a script, which they will execute against production server. since we don't have access to production database server and we can't compare and generate the incremental script.

What are the possible ways to handle the above problem? what things need to be done?

Comment: Depending on data schema compare could be not suffiecient. Imagine scenario where you want to `create unique index` and data inside table contains duplicates. Anyway you could always ask for schema only [`DBCC clonedatabase`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177838/how-to-use-dbcc-clonedatabase-to-generate-a-schema-and-statistics-only) do your compare, prepare script. It should be validated on non-production env and then run on PROD.

Comment: whatever changes I have done after initial deployment, I want to take those changes and generate a script and give it. but, I don't have access to production database server so I can't compare and generate the script. so I want to create only incremental script not the full database script.

Comment: 1) Ask for schema only PROD backup 2) Do your compare and create incremental script 3) You still won't be 100% it will work without real testing. Which part is unclear?

Comment: Is there a way without prod backup because it is restricted for me.

Comment: You may want to look into using a nuget package for the SSDT bits and see if you can give the customer the dacpac file, a Publish profile with proper production server settings (don't drop existing objects, allow deploys to different versions, etc). They might also be able to use SQLPackage to gen their own script from the dacpac and run that. That would be better than trying to gen a script against an unknown DB structure.